# Passing a value via prop, editing it and saving the new value vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to pass a value into a child component. The child component will then preform the save operation. The parent doesn't need to know anything about it. I am able to pass in the object but not save its updated form.

**Parent**

```html
<template>
    <div v-show="isOpened">
        <EditModal @toggle="closeModal" @update:todo="submitUpdate($event)"
            :updatedText="editText" :todo="modalPost" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import Post from "../components/Post.vue";
import { api } from "../lib/api";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { onMounted } from "vue-demi";
import EditModal from "../components/EditModal.vue";

const postArr = ref('');
const message = ref('');
let isOpened = ref(false);
let modalPost = ref('');
let editText = ref('');

function closeModal() {
    isOpened.value = false
}
function openModal(value: string) {
    isOpened.value = true
    modalPost.value = value
}

// call posts so the table loads updated item
function submitUpdate(value: any) {
    console.log("called update in parent  " + value)
    editText.value = value
    posts()
}
</script>
```

---

**Child EditModal**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="updateTextArea" rows="10" :value="props.todo.post"></textarea>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div>
            <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button"
                @click="update(props.todo.blogId, props.todo.post)">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { api } from "../lib/api";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
todo: String,
updatedText: String,
})

const emit = defineEmits(
['toggle','update:todo']
);

function setIsOpened(value: boolean) {
emit('toggle', value);
}

function update(id: string, value: string) {
console.log('the value   ' + value)
try {
api.updateBlog(id, value).then( res => {
emit('update:todo', value)
emit('toggle', false);
})
} catch (e) {
console.log('Error while updating post: '+ e)
}

}
</script>
```

I know the props are read only, therefore I tried to copy it I can only have one model.
I do not see the reason I should `$emit` to the parent and pass something to another variable to pass back to the child.
I am trying to pass in text to a modal component where it can edit the text and the child component saves it.

Advice?

Comment: AFAIU from code above. When child updates data you emit it to parent and in parent you want to save the data which you got from child here `editText.value = value
    posts()` ?

Comment: @Ankit.Z but I want the saving action to be in the child.

Comment: @Ankit.Z if I really have to do the save in the parent fine. But I need to pass the object not just the text which seem also not to be possible. I need the updated value and the ID in the $emit.

Comment: Why did you delete the question you asked before? Its same question!

Comment: @Mises I thought I solved it and removed it prematurely.

Comment: The OP says "I tried to copy it".  That's the right thing to do, but I don't see any evidence of that in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your component should be named `EditTodo` no `EditModal` because you are not editing modal. All `Edit` components should rewrite props to new local variables like ref or reactive, so you can work on them, they won't be read only any more.

**Child EditTodo.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="updateTextArea" rows="10" v-model="data.todo.title"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" type="button" @click="update()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { api } from "../lib/api";
import { reactive } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{ id: number, todo: { title: string} }>()
const emit = defineEmits(['toggle']);

const data = reactive({ ...props })

// I assuming api.updateBlog will update data in database
// so job here should be done just need toogle false modal
// Your array with todos might be not updated but here is
// no place to do that. Well i dont know how your API works.
// Database i use will automaticly update arrays i updated objects
function update() {
    try {
        api.updateBlog(data.id, data.todo ).then(res => {
            emit('toggle', false);
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

**Parent**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <BaseModal v-if="todo" :show="showModal">
            <EditTodo :id="todo.id" :todo="todo.todo" @toggle="(value) => showModal = value"></EditTodo>
        </BaseModal>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const showModal = ref(false)

const todo = reactive({ id: 5, todo: { title: "Todo number 5"} })

</script>
```

I separated a modal object with edit form, so you can create more forms and use same modal. And here is a simple, **not fully functional modal**.

```html
<template>
   <div class="..."><slot></slot></div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps(['show'])
defineEmits(['toogle'])
</script>
```

You might want to close modal when user click somewhere outside of modal.